# Не работает JavaScript на сайте

Tags: javascript

Не работает `javascript` на сайте! На планшете все работает, а на компьютере и смартфоне нет.

---

Это скрипт смены:

```
<script>
function next_banner()
{   
    $("#div_s1").fadeToggle(400, "linear");
    $("#div_s2").fadeToggle(400, "linear");

    setTimeout(next_banner, 4000);
}

var change_form_flag = 0;

function test_change_form()
{
    if(!change_form_flag)
    {   
        _tmr.push({ id: '2683702', type: 'reachGoal', goal: 'howmuch_start' });
        change_form_flag = 1;
    }
}
</script>
```

---

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема и как ее исправить?

Comment: Как оно должно работать, что значит «не работает», что в консоли пишет?

Comment: У Вас функции не вызываются. У меня в консольке работает (после небольшого напильника, конечно). Проблема может быть в Ваших браузерах. Включён JS? Только этот код не работает или вообще любой?